# Ajax Cannot Receive All JSON Array

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I got the problem when i tried to get the data from PHP using Ajax JSON, the PHP Output is :

```
"nilai2":[{"id":"7","nim":"122"},{"id":"4","nim":"122"},{"id":"6","nim":"122"},null]
```

but when i tried to print JSON data that was receive by AJAX it result only

```
"nilai2":{"id":"7","nim":"122"}
```

and this is my AJAX JSON script :

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url()?>penilaian/nilai_kelompok/'+id,
            
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(msg){
                 console.log(msg) } });
```

So the not All JSON data is passed when received by AJAX, anyone know the problem and solution?

Thanks